# Prove that : A < 1/5 < B for a Product of Fractions Sequence

Tags: inequality, fractions

Consider the numbers A and B such that:
$$A = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4} \cdots \frac{23}{24}$$
$$B = \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5} \cdots \frac{24}{25}$$
Prove that $A < 1/5 < B$.
My approach: honestly, I don't have any idea how I can compare $A$ and $B$, but I could show that one of them is less than 1/5 and the other is greater than 1/5. And that's by simply realizing that if $x < y$, then $x < \sqrt{xy} < y$, which means that if $A < B$, then $A < \sqrt{AB} < B$. From here, I tried to compute $AB$ as follows:
$$AB = \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots 23}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots 24} \cdot \frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots 24}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdots 25}$$
All terms cancel out, and I conclude that $AB = 1/25$, hence $\sqrt{AB} = 1/5$, hence $A < 1/5 < B$ if and only if $A < B$, which I couldn't show, unfortunately.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I really tried, but apparently latex here is not like discord for example

Answer (score 1):

The piece of information you need can be found by realizing that both $A$ and $B$ are a product of 12 positive fractions, such that the ith fraction in $A$ is always smaller than the ith fraction in $B$. Hence, $A<B$.

Comment: $-2<-1$ and $-3<-2$ but $(-2)\times(-3)=6>2=(-1)\times(-2)$.

Comment: @user10354138 sure, I was just replying to the specific question asked...

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: We have $0<\frac12<\frac23$, $0<\frac34<\frac45$, ..., $0<\frac{23}{24}<\frac{24}{25}$ so ...

Comment: Aha, so you basically mean that each one of the Fractions that compose the number B is greater than its equivalent in the number A, hence B>A, right?

Comment: Indeed, but you need positivity of the factors (see my other comment).

Comment: I see, thanks dude